# Storage of uncooked french fries

Tags: frying

How long can you store uncooked cut fries?  Tried to make some other day, didn't finish. Had quite a bit left over.....am currently storing them in water in refrigerator.  How long will they be safe to fry and eat? Or, can they?

Would estimate it's been at least 4-5 days.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

4-5 days would be a stretch.  Oxidation causes a taste and sight change to the cut fries that is typically un-appealing.  While 4-5 days; it would technically be safe to eat; the taste may be off.

Typically in restaurant world we would pre-cut and store for 24 hours in a water bath in the walk-in.

Alternatively they would be frozen; but this alters the flavor also (somewhat less though)...

Comment: I've read that potatoes should be par-cooked before freezing.

Comment: Double fry makes a huge difference in texture and taste; typically low temp first and then higher temp after.

Not sure if its related; but you could definitely use pending on taste profile you wanted.  Double fry always results in more crunch.